# Longest chain IUPAC rule

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I wonder, what are the exact IUPAC organic chemistry nomenclature rules that give the preference to the chain length over number of unsaturated bonds, i.e. that justify, or prefer following names:

[image: structure 1]

4-ethenyl-4-ethynylheptane *over*
3,3-dipropylpent-1-en-4-yne

[image: structure 2]

3,5-dimethylideneheptane *over*
2,4-diethylpenta-1,4-diene

?

Comment: afterwards I have found this related question: [What does the newest IUPAC nomenclature have against unsaturation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/what-does-the-newest-iupac-nomenclature-have-against-unsaturation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Chapter P-4 "Rules for Name Construction", section P-44 "Seniority Order for Parent Structures", of *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013*, it is stated that (p 490):

> **P-44.3.2** The principal chain has the greater number of skeletal atoms [criterion (b) in P-44.3].

The Blue Book lists several helpful examples, one of which is that the principal chain "octane" is senior to "hept-1-ene". Therefore, the following compound

[image: Compound to be named]

is named 3-methylideneoctane instead of 2-ethylhept-1-ene.

The authors mention that this preference is in contrast to previous recommendations (e.g. [1979](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_933.htm)):

> In acyclic parent structures the order of seniority between unsaturation and length of chain given in earlier recommendations is reversed. Thus, the first criterion to be considered in choosing a preferred parent acyclic chain is the length of the chain; unsaturation is now the second.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the reasons leading to this change are mentioned somewhere..