# Priority to longest carbon chain or double bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Priority to longest carbon chain or double bond?

[image]

Above structure and its nomenclature is given in my notes. However, I suspect it is wrong because the Carbon chain of 8 instead of 7 is available. So my question is do we give preference to double bond over the number of carbon in a chain during nomenclature?

I found [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74284/longest-chain-iupac-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1) question here but it only makes me more confuse as its answer states that we give preference to the carbon chain. So is my notes are outdated(which is possible) or is there any other rule which I am unaware of?

Comment: The answer by orthocresol should apply to your current one. I am on app and can't see the sketch to see if you are right and the book wrong. Perhaps the authors refer to prior 1979...